# Request Optimization (CTE, multiple LEFT JOIN, WHERE with OR)

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

Can anyone give me advice on how to optimize this request?

More left joins than in this example (20+), principally to get values with foreign key, what optimization is possible?

CTE used to create aggregates but CTE tables are used in principal request, so is it useful?

Where condition with a simple condition on the principal table and a second condition OR with fields of several tables, could it be better to add a column with a max date of the 3 fields and have a simple second condition (without OR)?

SQL Server 2015+

```
WITH
cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        e_ofcte.id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN f_ofcte.lib='G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS n1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN f_ofcte.lib='H' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS n2
    FROM e_ofcte
    INNER JOIN f_ofcte ON f_ofcte.id=e_ofcte.id
    WHERE f_ofcte.lib IN ('G','H')
        AND e_ofcte.date>=DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-2,1,1)
    GROUP BY 
        e_ofcte.id
)

SELECT 
    a.id, 
    b.sid, 
    c.sid,
    cte.n1,
    cte.n2
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN cte ON a.id=cte.id 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.id 
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id=c.id
LEFT JOIN e_ofcte ON a.id=e_ofcte.id
LEFT JOIN i ON a.id=i.id
LEFT JOIN j ON a.id=j.id
LEFT JOIN f_ofcte ON a.id=f_ofcte.id
WHERE a.code='A'
    AND 
        (
        a.date>=>=DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-2,1,1)
        OR
        b.date>=>=DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-2,1,1)
        OR
        c.date>=>=DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-2,1,1)
        )
```

Comment: can you paste the execution plan?  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Why are you joining to a number of tables but then not using any of the columns in those tables (i, j, etc)?

Comment: The columns of the others tables are used. I will paste the execution plan. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I won't be able to paste the execution plan because of privacy.

Comment: I'm not sure why pasting the execution plan has any greater privacy concerns than pasting the SQL, but if that is the case... Can you at least paste the full SQL statement? If there are any constant values that give you privacy concerns then you can replace them with 'x's or something similar

Answer (score 0):

If you move "OR" conditions to JOIN it will return different results. My answer would be "NO", unless you exactly know what you are doing.

There are multiple possible approaches you can try to fight performance:

1. Move CTE to temporary table if you can. It makes query smaller?
   which will help optimizer to come up with the best plan. Also, you
   can tune two parts separately.
2. Possibly build filtered index on table A(id,date) with "WHERE
   code='A'" - that would work if number of filtered records is
   relatively small
3. Possibly build filtered index on table f_ofcte(id) with "WHERE
   lib IN ('G','H')"
4. Build indexes on other tables on (id,date)
5. Not sure if you provided full query, but it looks like following
   part is completely unused:

---

```
LEFT JOIN e_ofcte ON a.id=e_ofcte.id
LEFT JOIN i ON a.id=i.id
LEFT JOIN j ON a.id=j.id
LEFT JOIN f_ofcte ON a.id=f_ofcte.id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I will try to move the CTEin temp table, should I try to move the first table a with her where condition in another temp table? I didn't past the full request, yes the fields of other tables with left join are used like b.sid, c.sid.Thanks

Comment: If there is a small portion of used records in table "A" it is easier just to create filtered index. If you put it into a temp table you might have to create an index on it anyway